# Where does PublishPipelineArtifact@1 write output? How do I access the files from later stages?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have 2 stages: **build** & **deploy**

In the **build** stage, my publish task looks like:

```
   - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
     inputs:
       targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/funcabc-1.1.0.zip
       artifactName: functionapp
```

After running the build stage, I can see the artifact in the Azure Pipeline portal/UI. In the completed pipeline run, I click on Artifacts | Published. The file appears.
Good so far!

My deployment job/steps are in a different **stage**. I deploy with something like:

```
  - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'valid_srv_conn
      appType: functionApp
      appName: funcabc
      package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/functionapp/funcabc-1.1.0.zip
```

I have tried many combinations for the path to package:. The deploy stage is unable to find funcabc-1.1.0.zip.

For troubleshooting, I am running:

```
  - pwsh: |
      Get-ChildItem -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace) -Filter *.zip -Recurse | Select-Object FullName
      Get-ChildItem -Path "./" -Filter *.zip -Recurse | Select-Object FullName
```

The troubleshooting script shows 0 file results.

How do I access a published .zip file from a downstream stage?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I access a published .zip file from a downstream stage?

You need to add the [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) in different stages(deploy stage).

For example:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    artifactName: 'functionapp'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

Then the artifacts in build stage can be used in the deploy stage.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Publish and download pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#download-artifacts)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer to **How do I access the files in later stages**?

I simply changed for a generic job: to a deploy: job:.

Originally, the -task: AzureFunctionApp@1 step was throwing error "##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/s/functionapp/funcabc-1.1.0.zip
Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job"

Originally, my job: was setup like this:

```
jobs:
- job: deploy_func
  steps:
    -task: AzureFunctionApp@1
```

I change the jobs: type to strategy: deploy:

```
jobs:
- job: deploy_func
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
         -task: AzureFunctionApp@1
```